Better to delete/repost or request migration?
My question about Debian on an iMac hasn't gotten much attention, and I'd like to try it on https://unix.stackexchange.com/.  I'm happy to delete and repost there, or flag for moderator attention. Is one or the other preferred?  Why?

Jeff Atwood (!) comments on this question that it's OK to delete and repost if the question hasn't gotten any answers (it does have an upvote in this case, though)
or I could flag for migration (I don't have enough rep to vote to close it myself) [For what it's worth it looks like at least as of 2023 unix.stackexchange.com wasn't available as a migration target anyway ... ?)


You can’t close your own question

OK, but I could still flag for migration. (Someone commented on the question that I could delete and re-post, so I might just go ahead and do it ...)

You could be that would require a custom moderator flag since Unix isn’t a migration target for SU, so you can flag and wait, or delete and repost immediately

I went ahead and deleted/reposted. Should I delete this question too, or will it be useful to someone in the future?

There is nothing wrong with this question

There's a select set of target sister sites the community is able to vote to migrate towards. Migration to other sites requires special moderator action.
If you're migrating to one of those that is on the current list of available migration targets, asking here for the community to vote to migrate is the right thing. But if you need your question to get to one of the many SE sites not available for easy migration, deletion and recreation is the right course of action, as you've already done.
